# Возникла проблема при алгоритме if :TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, for, request

Возникла проблема, в моем коде данные записываются в словарь, в графе "sell" может быть как цена, так и пустая графа, поэтому хотел сделать простой алгоритм if, где если в вышеуказанной строке будет результат: None, в словаре появится фраза: нет запросов на покупку, но тут возникла проблема, связанная с типами значений, не знаю как исправить. Мой код:

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import csv
import time

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Arms%20of%20the%20Onyx%20Crucible%20Shoulders'
s = Service('C:\\Users\\Семен\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\Parser\\geckodriver.exe')
CSV = 'C:\\Users\\Семен\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\Parser\\weapon.csv'
def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'
    }

    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    with open('index.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(r.text)


def get_data_s(url):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.set_preference('general.useragent.override', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36')

    # try:
    #     driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    #        options = options
    #     )
    #     driver.get(url=url)
    #     time.sleep(2)
    #
    #     with open('index_s.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    #         file.write(driver.page_source)
    #
    # except Exception as ex:
    #     print(ex)
    # finally:
    #     driver.close()
    #     driver.quit()

with open('index_s.html', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = bs(src, 'lxml')
info = soup.find_all('div', id="mainContents")
names = []
for name in info:
    names.append(
        {
            'Name': name.find('h1', class_='hover_item_name').text,
            'Sost': name.find('div', class_='descriptor').text.replace('Износ: ',''),
            'sell':  name.find('span', class_='market_commodity_orders_header_promote'),#.get_text(), #.text.replace('$','') (Если надо удалить знак $)
            'buy : 1 poz': name.findAll('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee')[0].text.replace('\t', "").replace('\n', ''),
            'buy : 2 poz': name.findAll('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee')[1].text.replace('\t', "").replace('\n', ''),
            'buy : 3 poz': name.findAll('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee')[2].text.replace('\t', "").replace('\n', ''),
        }
    )

if names['sell'] == 'None':
    names['sell'] == 'нет запросов на покупку'
print(names)


try:
    with open( CSV, 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Название', 'Состояние', 'Цена продажи', 'Цена покупки (1 предложение)', 'Цена покупки (2 предложение)', 'Цена покупки (3 предложение)'])
        for name in names:
             writer.writerow([name['Name'], name['Sost'], name['sell'], name['buy : 1 poz'], name['buy : 2 poz'], name['buy : 3 poz']])
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")




def main():
    # get_data('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case')
    get_data_s(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
Дело в том, что ссылка на товар может меняться, поэтому значения в строках тоже динамичные. Буду благодарен за помощь.
````

Comment: names-список.У списка нет ключей, есть индексы

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что у тебя проблема со срезами списков. В ошибке сказано, что ты пытаешься сделать срез списка с помощью строки "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".
В твоем коде есть строчки:

```
names = []
if names['sell'] == 'None'
```

В списке ты можешь обращаться к индексу элемента.
Если ты хочешь выполнить проверку какого-либо элемента, то names[n], где вместо n у тебя будет число.
Если ты хочешь выяснить, пустой ли список, то можешь так:

```
if names:
   print('нет запросов на покупку')
```

Comment: У меня в списке всего один элемент, это словарь, поэтому по запросу print(names[0]) печатается весь словарь. Спасибо за совет, но данный способ не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in info:
    sell = name.find('span', class_='market_commodity_orders_header_promote')
    if sell == None:
        sell = 'нет запросов на покупку'
    names.append(
        {
            'Name': name.find('h1', class_='hover_item_name').text,
            'Sost': name.find('div', class_='descriptor').text.replace('Износ: ',''),
            'sell':  sell,
            'buy : 1 poz': name.findAll('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee')[0].text.replace('\t', "").replace('\n', ''),
            'buy : 2 poz': name.findAll('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee')[1].text.replace('\t', "").replace('\n', ''),
            'buy : 3 poz': name.findAll('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee')[2].text.replace('\t', "").replace('\n', ''),
        }
    )
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению алгоритм не работает, значение 'sell' все так же 'None', пробовал sell приравнять к пустой строчке - ' ', но тоже ничего не вышло. Не понимаю почему. Извините за беспокойство, уже исправил в графе с алгоритмом if None надо было указать без опострафов.